# Problem with OBS studio

Tags: pulseaudio

Using a Zoom R16 as multi input audio interface, ALSA, and pulse audio, how do I get input from the R16 to OBS studio. All 8 inputs show on the decibel indicator and produce output to headphones and amplifier, but no input or output capture is occurring.

Comment: Which supported Ubuntu release are you using? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 but I resolved the problem with new hardware thanks.